# .Net Core 2.0 REST API w/ Windows Auth - Preflight responding with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using .NET Core 2.0 and Angular 4 to create a web page locally. I am able to get my front end to successfully submit GET request, but not POST. I have tried every which way to enable CORS and Windows Authentication, but I'm always getting an Unauthorized error. What am I missing here to get past pre-flight? I'm assuming it has something to do with windows authentication, but everything I find just says I need the 'withCredentials:true' header option.

**Angular Service**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  }),
  withCredentials: true
};

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private baseURL = 'http://localhost:58214/api/{insert_app_name_here}';

  getAllRules() {
    console.log('Getting rules');
    return this.http.get<RuleItem>(this.baseURL).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  createNewRule(ri: RuleItem) {
    return this.http.post<RuleItem>(this.baseURL, JSON.stringify(ri), httpOptions).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log('Error occurred: ', err);
    });
  }

}
```

**.NET CORE 2.0 Controller**

```
// [EnableCors("SitePolicy")]
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        private readonly RuleContext _context;

        public TestController(RuleContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<RuleItem> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.RuleItems.ToList();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetRule")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            var item = _context.RuleItems.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(RuleItem item)
        {

            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.RuleItems.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }

    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            /*
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SitePolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);*/

            services.AddMvc();

            var connection = @"Server=servername;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
            services.AddDbContext<RuleContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // app.UseCors("SitePolicy");

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

**web.config**
not sure if I need this if I have the CORS added programmatically, but this was the only solution that successfully got rid of the "no allow-origin header present" error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT** - Made the following changes: Removed web.config file, added global CORS rules. Here are the changes:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {


        services.AddCors();

        //services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddMvc();

        var connection = @"Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
        services.AddDbContext<RuleContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        private readonly RuleContext _context;

        public TestController(RuleContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<RuleItem> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.RuleItems.ToList();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetRule")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            var item = _context.RuleItems.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(RuleItem item)
        {

            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.RuleItems.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }
}
```

Here is an image of the error message I am now receiving:[401 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10r2y.png)

Comment: You don't need to edit your web.config (you don't need to provide one either, `dotnet publish` will create one automatically). All you need to enable CORS is to add `app.UseCors(builder => builder                    .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials())` to your application pipeline.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought initially. I have typed that exact code but it didn’t work. I was receiving the ‘no allow-origin header specified’ error. I tried with AllowAnyOrigin and then explicitly defining my http://localhost:4200 as the only allowed origin

Comment: The middleware already handles that. You can test CORS with postman by setting the `Origin` header. You might need to disable a setting in postman because he might override the origin. Basically, if you set the origin header to something different than your PC's hostname, the middleware should be triggered and it should add the CORS headers to the response.

Comment: Also, if you define a policy name, you should have the `[EnableCors("PolicyName")]` attribute on your controller. If you apply it like I told you, it doesn't have a policy name and it should be applied globally to your application, without any attribute.

Comment: I've added the changes you've specified and am still having issues. Please see the error in the update. Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is not your dotnet core application that returns the response; it's IIS. You're not authenticated, therefore IIS returns a 401. IIS is not configured to have CORS, therefore, you have a CORS issue in your application. I've had the same issues and there's no easy way out. I had to install a CORS extension package for IIS to make it work, and it wouldn't work in development with IIS Express. You can use the custom headers with a web.config, but you'll have a different set of problems. In short, IIS is bad with CORS and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: You're right, I guess I'm not appropriately passing the token. At least it was a good learning experience. I will play around with the NTLM token and verify this was the issue and close it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: The issue was indeed with the token. I was not passing the token appropriately, hence it was failing preflight! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being with passing the Windows token. The token was not being checked in the preflight request, hence the failure.

Comment: Could you kindly show how did you pass the windows token? And did it work on development environment??